# one to one correspondence with uniform pdf

Tags: probability, density-function

If $R \sim \text{Uniform}(0, 1)$, and I define a circle to have radius $R$, and I define a RV $A$ as the area of the circle, it follows that $A = \pi R^2$.

It took me a while to grasp why $A \sim \text{Uniform}(0, \pi)$ is not true, intuitively. I think I understand that $A$'s pdf $f_A(a)$ is not systematically mapping $a$ to a probability, because the probability of a specific point in a uniform distribution is $0$.

Instead, I turned to computations to solve for $f_A$.

$f_A(a) = f_R(r)$ where $r = \sqrt{\frac{a}{\pi}}$. But this get's to a similar point where I think that $A$ would be distributed uniformly. Could someone clarify why this is incorrect and how you generally should approach finding the pdf of a function of a random variable with a known disribution.

Comment: For some intuition, note that $P(R \le 1/2)=1/2$. This event corresponds to circles of area $\le \pi/4$, i.e. $P(A \le \pi/4) = 1/2$. So the area is definitely not uniform on $(0, \pi)$, since otherwise we would have $P(A \le \pi/2) = 1/2$ instead.

Comment: If you want to find the relationship between the densities of $R$ and $A$, you will need to do a [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar). Alternatively, work with the CDF instead, similar to my previous comment.